# Call object after created by action in C# Winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an action for my button in c# Winform like this:

```
 private void btnAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox tbxdg = new TextBox();
            tbxdg.Name = "tbx_DG" + cx.ToString();
            tbxdg.Location = new Point(508, 12 + (40 * cx));
            tbxdg.Size = new Size(200, 24);
            tbxdg.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 10);
            panel2.Controls.Add(tbxdg);

            cx++;
        }
```

Now I want to get text from the textbox that i've created by clicking my button. I've tried call the textbox by the name that i given to it in the button click action but it's not working.

Comment: Maybe something like `((TextBox) panel2.Controls.Where( c => c.Name == "tbx_DG0").First()).Text` assuming you add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your class and depending on what button click event you're talkig about.  Show us what you tried that didn't work and how it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can try this:

```
var textBoxText = panel2.Controls.Find("name of textbox", false).First().Text;
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is simple but work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private int cx = 0;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                TextBox tbxdg = new TextBox();
                tbxdg.Name = "tbx_DG" + cx.ToString();
                tbxdg.Location = new Point(0, 0 + (40 * cx));
                tbxdg.Size = new Size(200, 24);
                tbxdg.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 10);
                panel1.Controls.Add(tbxdg);

                cx++;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = string.Empty;
            foreach (TextBox tb in panel1.Controls)
            {
                label1.Text += $"{tb.Name} - {tb.Text}\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl0gK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching the control name in the panel, another approach is to add all the dynamic text boxes to global `List<TextBox>`
Please read comments inside the example:

```
private int cx;
private List<TextBox> DynamicTextBoxesList = new List<TextBox>();

private void btnAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tbxdg = new TextBox();
    tbxdg.Name = "tbx_DG" + cx.ToString();
    tbxdg.Location = new Point(508, 12 + (40 * cx));
    tbxdg.Size = new Size(200, 24);
    tbxdg.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 10);
    panel2.Controls.Add(tbxdg);
    // add to list
    DynamicTextBoxesList.Add(tbxdg);
    cx++;
}

// button event for example how to use DynamicTextBoxesList
private void btnExampleFoaccesingTextBoxes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DynamicTextBoxesList.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (TextBox t in DynamicTextBoxesList)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(t.Text);
        }

        // or you can find by name for example you need cx=1:
        var txtbox = DynamicTextBoxesList.Where(x => x.Name == "tbx_DG1").FirstOrDefault();
        if (txtbox != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(txtbox.Text);
        }
    }
}
```